# Can I modify a CSS variable from VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-modules, css-variables

CSS Modules let us use the variable in both CSS and JS.

```
// use in temaplate
...
...<p :class="{ [$style.red]: isRed }">Am I red?</p>

// use in js 
...
...
<script>
export default {
    created () {
        console.log(this.$style.red)
        // -> "red_1VyoJ-uZ"
        // an identifier generated based on filename and className.
    }
}
</script>

/// use in css preprocessor
...
...
<style lang="stylus" module>
.red {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

We can get the variable no matter in template, JS or CSS. But if we have some feature like: click and change all website's "main-color" which define in CSS.

Can we change the variable in JS?

Comment: actually `$style.red: true` just adds a class red to your element. And in your css you can do `.red { color: red }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS Module is a CSS file in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default

So use them when you want to be sure a component style will not overridden.

> I am not sure what you asking for so I am assuming you want to dynamically change the css module class.

Template:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div :class="[module]">I am a div</div>
   <button @click="make_blue_class">Make it blue</button>
   <button @click="make_red_class">Make it red</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
  data: () => ({
    module_class: 'red'
  }),

  computed: {
    module: {
      get() {
        return this.$style[this.module_class]
      },
      set(new_class) {
        this.module_class = new_class
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    make_blue_class() {
      this.module_class = 'blue'
    },
    make_red_class() {
      this.module_class = 'red'
    }
  }
```

Style:

```
  .red {
    background: red;
  }
  .blue {
    background: blue;
  }
```

[See it in action here](https://codesandbox.io/s/93098o2oy4)

Comment: Yes, I want to control the variable in js. In this solution, we need to define the class first, but what if the variable is defined by the user? I know we can use css var(), is there any idea in css module?

Comment: "The variable is defined by the user." You mean the user can define the class? just bind dynamically the class variable combine it with $style[user_value]

Comment: I just mix the class and the variable, sorry. I want to let user control the website's main-color variable which defined in css. I think it can still fulfill by css var(). It's not a question about css module. sorry@@

Comment: How does this work with multiple classes? Say `.red.container`?

Comment: you just add array `class="[$style.red, $style.container]"`